# Ubuntu 20.04 slider brightness

Tags: 20.04, brightness

I use Ubuntu 18.04.Right now I'm using VMware , I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 just to see any differences between 18.04 and 20.04 and I don't see anywhere the brightness slider.Do you know why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu 20.04 inside the virtual machine won't actually be aware of your laptop's display (it is actually using a "virtual" display). That's why it can't control your laptop's screen brightness.

If you test Ubuntu 20.04 with a Live USB (without installing) you should be able to see the brightness slider, or use your laptop's function keys to control the brightness.